# Postman shows 404 while the rest api is actually called

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, postman

I have the below spring boot api which I am trying to call from Postman :

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping(value = "/productList", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public List<Product> listAllProducts() {
    // fetch products and send the list
    List<Product> products = somemethod();
    logger.info("No of products fetched : " + products.size());
    return products;
}
```

**Postman URL :** `GET --> http://localhost:5000/shop/productList`

This is my response in postman :

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-07-21T13:05:48.431+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/shop/productList"
}
```

I could see the logs are printing correct values. I am not sure what happening in return response.
Initially the return type was `ResponseEntity` and I changed it to `List<Product>`. After that it stopped working.

Comment: What does the logs say? Do you have a `ControllerAdvice` in your application?

Comment: @aksappy : Log is priniting the size of products correctly. `@Controller
@RefreshScope
@RequestMapping("/shop")`

Comment: With postman, you execute the following? `GET --> localhost:8080/shop/productList`. I tried your code, and works perfectly :/

Comment: Try Using `@RestController` on your class, or `@ResponseBody` on your method?

Comment: Yes @ZIHAOLIU is right, change your `@Controller` to `@RestController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning a List requires your Controller to be able to serialize the Output. As stated by ZIHAO LIU, for that you would need a class-level @RestController annotation or @ResponseBody on your method.

If you don't want to add these annotations, you could also wrap your List in a ResponseEntity, like so:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping(value = "/productList", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> listAllProducts() {
    // fetch products and send the list
    List<Product> products = somemethod();
    logger.info("No of products fetched : " + products.size());
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(products);
}
```

In any case you will need to return a ResponseEntity if you are not using one of above annotations.